# How to select the closest element with a specific tag in chai protractor

Tags: protractor, cucumber, chai

If the html looks as follow:

```
<form>
   <div>
      <field-component>
         <div class='field'></div>
      </field-component>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class='icon'></div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I am able to get the field using `fieldElement = element(by.css('.field'))`, but how can I get the closest element with the `icon` class?

Comment: can you paste more code? where those `divs` are embedded?

Comment: @Kacper They are in the same form

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var form = element(by.css('form'));

return form.element(by.css('.field')).isPresent().then((present) => {
    if (present) {
        return form.element(by.css('.icon')).click(); #click or whatever on this element
    }
});
```